# Should there be an option to ask "sub-questions?"

Tags: discussion, comments, questions, multiple-questions

I have run into multiple situations where I will ask a question and then a comment or answer will raise another related question. However, it seems that simply adding the new question in the comments is not quite adequate because a comment section could get overrun with other things, and so the "sub-question" goes unanswered or otherwise overlooked. In addition, if the sub-question is sufficiently complicated, it just looks less clean to write it in the comments.

What about creating a "sub-question" thread rather than a "general comments" thread? Has this idea ever been put forth before? Or maybe there is a way to implement "sub-questions" by raising a totally new question thread that is linked to the old one, for instance?

Comment: Related from the answerer perspective, but might also help the asker to know what to do: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The review comment which is automatically added when someone clicks *Delete*/*Recommend Deletion* from the queue is

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review - user1

and the reaction should be no different when someone does this in comments.

The problem is already solved. This "sub-question" idea does it worse and would require more work to develop.